# How to remove prompt on unload event using javascript

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

How can I remove prompt on unload event using javascript? thanks in advance...

hm, I don't want to show the prompt when firing the custom function for the unlaod event of the body... Is it possible? so here's my code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    //cancel the unload
            //cancel prompt
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your event handler doesn't have a `return` statement in it. Returning from the function triggers the conformation message.

Update based on the code comments in the edited question: If the user does something to leave the page, then you can tell the browser to ask them if they are sure. You **cannot** silently prevent them. If the user wishes to leave the page, then they can do so (dodgy sites full of adverts and/or malware would love it to be otherwise, thankfully it isn't)

Comment: Hm, it's like cancelling the unload event in a silent mode... something like that...

Comment: So you mean there's no way to do that? Are you 100% sure? Thanks in advance... Wait, do you have any reference? I just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, there is no way to do it. The specification isn't clear on that point, but some basic experimentation shows it to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly NOT impossible.  All you have to do to suppress the prompt is omit the "return" statement.  Returning any value will cause the prompt to fire.  Example:

```
           window.onbeforeunload = function saveAllData()
            {
                //Invoke AJAX method to save DataTable in database
                [classname].SaveDataTable();
                //return true;                      //comment out 'return' to suppress prompt
            }

            function SaveDataTable_Callback(response) 
            {
                //alert(response);
            }
```

Comment: The main problem that I observe that omitting return value omits the whole function, the function which I assigned to onbeforeunload is not invoked at all.