# Removing the prompt box onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove prompt on unload event using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042071/how-to-remove-prompt-on-unload-event-using-javascript)

I am working on a Javascript that runs onbeforeunload and onunload now the script generally runs fine, however on IE and Firefox it will run a prompt asking if you want to leave or not and regardless of the choice you select the rest of the code is executed still. Now on Chrome and Safari it doesn't have this problem. I am trying to figure out why IE and Firefox does it and to try to remove it from showing a prompt box all together. Here is the code I have if it helps:

```
var leave_message = document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerCloseSubmit");
var leave_safari = document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerCloseSafari");

function goodbye(e) {
    if (!validNavigation) {
        if (dont_confirm_leave!==1) {
            leave_message.click();
            if(!e) e = window.event;

            //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = leave_message.click();

            //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            //return works for Chrome and Safari
            //canceling this makes IE work well but not make Safari work at all.
            leave_safari.click();
        }
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
window.onunload=leave; 

function leave() {
    document.getElementById('kioskform:broswerCloseSubmit').click();           
}
```

Comment: what are `leave_message.click();` and `leave_safari.click();`?

Comment: they connect to a command button that removes and resets the form. I just added the variables to them above hope it helps in understanding better sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6042071/259457

Comment: I read it and sadly I need the returnValue were its at or safari will not work at all. I need to think of something else or is there a way to rig the code to show if its only for safari?